# How to copy/re-apply changes from a certain revision to the working/head revision?

Tags: svn

We're working on a project, then suddenly some uncooperative/stubborn guy get in and checked in something that messed up the project - made it un-buildable but has no effect on my modules. So we're still working while using the last known working revision and I checked in my changes like normal. Then the project manager resolved to reverting back everything to the last known working revision(r1810) and it became r1824.

Now, how to re-apply my revisions from 1814, 1815, and 1821?

I'm using Tortoise SVN on Windows explorer and AnkhSVN on Visual Studio most of the time so I can say that I'm still a newbie in using the command prompt while working on SVN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to "cherry-pick" these changes.

To cite [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking):

> <…> the term cherrypicking. This word refers to the act of choosing
>   one specific changeset from a branch and replicating it to another.
>   Cherrypicking may also refer to the act of duplicating a particular
>   set of (not necessarily contiguous!) changesets from one branch to
>   another. This is in contrast to more typical merging scenarios, where
>   the “next” contiguous range of revisions is duplicated automatically.

To cherry-pick, use `svn merge -c 1814 ^whatever/branch`;
again, to cite [`the manual`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.change):

> `--change (-c) ARG`
>
> Perform the requested operation using a specific “change”.
>   Generally speaking, this option is syntactic sugar for `-r ARG-1:ARG`.
>   Some subcommands permit a comma-separated list of revision
>   number arguments (e.g., `-c ARG1,ARG2,ARG3`). Alternatively, you can
>   provide two arguments separated by a dash (as in `-c ARG1-ARG2`) to
>   identify the range of revisions between `ARG1` and `ARG2`, inclusive.
>   Finally, if the revision argument is negated, the implied revision
>   range is reversed: `-c -45` is equivalent to `-r 45:44`.

**Update:** as sugested by the OP, they needed to use the
`--ignore-ancestry` command-line option to `svn merge -c` since they are
using the single branch for development.

Comment: Thanks, still hesitant to use the command prompt because I might mess up the project too so I found a way to do it on TortoiseSVN. Becaue we're working only on a single branch, I have to add the option --ignore-ancestry.

Comment: @eSPiYa I did not actually mean to suggest using the command-line (even though I prefer doing just that)—it's just we should have some common ground when talking about these matters; for VC tools, their command-line interface is usually that common ground. It (should be) reasonably straightforward to map its approaches to higher-level tools, while the reverse is usually harder (and the tools differ).